# How to add a color frame to a plot?

Tags: r, plot

For some reasons I want to add a frame to a plot like this:

[image]

Can I do this in `plot`? `ggplot` or `qplot` solutions are also welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set.seed(123); 
plot(x=rnorm(100, sd=1000), y=rnorm(100, sd=1000) ,ylab="", xlab="")
rect(xleft=par("usr")[1]*1.25, ybottom=par("usr")[3]*1.4, 
     xright=par("usr")[2]*1.1,ytop=par("usr")[4]*1.2, 
     lwd=5, border="orange", xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What are the magic numbers `1.25`, `1.4`, `1.1` and `1.2` here?

Comment: OK otherwise axes will be excluded.

Comment: Extended question: if I export the plot to PNG, how can I only export the portion within the frame?

Comment: @ziyuang , for png, I think it is better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

```
qplot(x= disp , y = wt , data = mtcars) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour="#CF8057",size=10))
```

[image]

Comment: That wasn't what was requested. If it were then in base graphics it would be a s simple as `box(lwd=5, col="orange")`.

Comment: @Dwin Sorry I get it now. I had to use plot.backgroud and not panel.background. I update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can draw a solid rectangle, then using `print(.., vp=..)` plot your ggplot over it, shrinking it down slightly.

Here is an example in a nice little function:

```
borderize <- function(plotObj, thick=2, color="orange", alpha=0.8) {
  # thick should be a value between (1, 100)
  # alpha should be a value between (0, 1)

  # these could be modified for separate width/height thicknesses
  wd <- ht <-  (100 - thick) / 100
  x <- (1 - wd)  / 2 
  y <- (1 - ht) / 2

  # create a solid rectangle.  The plot will go over it. 
  grid.rect(y = 1, height = 1, just = c("center", "top"), gp=gpar(fill=color, alpha=alpha, lwd=0))

  # create the viewport
  vp.inner <- viewport(height=unit(ht, "npc"), width=unit(wd, "npc"), just=c("left","bottom"), y=y, x=x)

  print(plotObj, vp=vp.inner)

}
```

#### eg:

```
myPlot <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + 
                 geom_point(aes(color=Species,shape=Species))

borderize(myPlot, thick=5, color="#CF8042")
```

[image: ggplot2 with border]

Note that you can also modify `plot.background` and `panel.background` with theme() in ggplot2.
However, this will impact your labels and legend, depending on the thickness of border, font size etc. 
Thats why I prefer to use viewport.

eg:

```
plot.bg  <- theme(plot.background=element_rect(color="red", size=12))
panel.bg <- theme(panel.background=element_rect(color="blue", size=12))

plotObj + panel.bg + plot.bg
```

red border is `plot`,  blue border is `panel`

[image]
**NOTICE HOW THE BORDER EATS INTO THE LABELS**

The *advantage* of using `plot.background` however is that you can save the whole graph as an object; something you cannot do using the `borderize` method above.

Comment: Thanks for your ggplot solution. Currently I am using the plain `plot`, but I think `ggplot` is more flexible and worth heavy investigation.